# Firebase Performance - Crashlytics

Tags: java, android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-performance

I'm using firebase performance. And it's annoying to see them constantly in the log records. Is it wrong somewhere or why it turns out that log records;

```
W/FirebaseRemoteConfig: No value of type 'FirebaseRemoteConfigValue' exists for parameter key 'fpr_session_max_duration_min'.
W/FirebaseRemoteConfig: No value of type 'FirebaseRemoteConfigValue' exists for parameter key 'fpr_enabled'.
W/FirebaseRemoteConfig: No value of type 'FirebaseRemoteConfigValue' exists for parameter key 'fpr_disabled_android_versions'.
W/FirebaseRemoteConfig: No value of type 'FirebaseRemoteConfigValue' exists for parameter key 'fpr_enabled'.
W/FirebaseRemoteConfig: No value of type 'FirebaseRemoteConfigValue' exists for parameter key 'fpr_disabled_android_versions'.
W/FirebaseRemoteConfig: No value of type 'FirebaseRemoteConfigValue' exists for parameter key 'fpr_vc_network_request_sampling_rate'.
```

build.gradle (module)

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-perf'

    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:$firebase.firebase_analytics"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:$firebase.messaging"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:$firebase.auth"
    implementation "com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:$firebase.crashlytics"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:$firebase.firestore"
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:19.0.4'
```

build.gradle (project)

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.2'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.31.0'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:perf-plugin:1.3.1'

        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$libraries.kotlin_version"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }

firebase = [
                firebase_analytics: '17.2.1',
                messaging         : '20.1.0',
                auth              : '19.2.0',
                crashlytics       : '2.10.1',
                firestore         : '21.3.1'

        ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase Performance Monitoring uses Firebase Remote Config for some things internally.  This is normal, but there's nothing you can do to stop them from being logged.  If you'd rather not see those message in the log, then [file a feature request with Firebase support](https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support).

Comment: I hope it is as you say. I'm sending feedback for the feature request. Thank you for your help

Comment: It looks that it is still happening. Did they respond to you?

Answer (score 1):

```
        <meta-data
            android:name="firebase_performance_logcat_enabled"
            android:value="true" />
```

If I remove this tag in the manifest I don't see the logs.